# Boot USB for windows from Linux Distributuin(winUSB not working)

Tags: boot, usb, windows, tools

I want to know about creating a bootable USB from *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/Linux Mint 18.2*(my friend PC) for *Windows*.

**Problem:** I normally write an image to USB using `Disk Image Writer` tool. But when I tried to write Windows 10 iso image, after copying all files to USB it **cannot finish making it bootable**.

I do some researches for that and some blogs were suggesting **winUSB** tool. But I find it complex to install and after successfully installing it exit with error.

```
Installation failed ! Exit code: 256
```

Other tools like **Etcher**, **Gnome Multi Writer**, **Multibootusb** have the same effect of ***Disk Image Writer***

So, can anyone suggest anything for me?

*GUI app* or `terminal` - no problem

Thanks

Comment: Try MKUSB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: Do you want to run Windows from USB or just install it? If run it, install Ubuntu to USB, install Vbox and run Windows as a Virtual machine.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron No. I just want to make it bootable

Comment: @MichaelBay mkusb really works at last. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert your usb key in your PC and check the path of the key with the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Supposing your usb key is identified with `/dev/sdb` (normally `/dev/sda` is your main drive) unmount the key with the command

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

Once unmounted you are ready to flash Win iso on the key with the following command

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=[/path/to/your/win/image].iso of=/dev/sdb
```

**Beware:** when you launch `dd` command, it could take several minute with no output to end. Let it go on!

Comment: Thanks for the help. but same problem with these lines too. copies all files, but can't make bootable.